# Evaluate the numerical value of three Kronecker delta

Tags: vector-analysis, index-notation, kronecker-delta

How to go about evaluating the numerical value of three Kronecker delta:
$$\delta_{ii}\delta_{jj}\delta_{kk}$$

Tried summing at like this: $$\delta_{ii}\delta_{jj}\delta_{kk}=\delta_{ii}\delta_{ii}\delta_{ii}+\delta_{jj}\delta_{jj}\delta_{jj}+\delta_{kk}\delta_{kk}\delta_{kk}=(3)(3)(3)+(3)(3)(3)+(3)(3)(3)=81$$

But it was marked incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by numerical value?

Comment: Are you using the Einstein summation convention?  What values can the indices take?

Comment: $\delta^i_i\delta^j_j\delta^k_k=n\cdot n\cdot n=n^3$ where $n$ is your number of dimensions. Not sure how you get three summands here.

Comment: finding the scalar value. yes using Einstein summation